# Furry Bug that swarms only certain plant

Tags: species-identification

What is this strange bug?

It swarms only on one certain plant with trumpet-shaped red flowers (in the picture the flowers are all shriveled and the leaves are in the foreground) and totally coats it until the bush dries up. It spreads very rapidly but only to this particular plant - will not touch any other. The bugs don't noticeably move, giving the impression that the whole bush has developed white fur.

Picture taken in Israel:[image: Fluffy white Bugs]

EDIT:

Here's a closeup of a single specimen (taken from one of the leaves in the foreground): [image]

And it seems the plant is a hibiscus:
http://homeguides.sfgate.com/hibiscus-leaf-87355.html

Comment: almost certainly a scale insect (or, less likely, some kind of aphid). Can't seem to get the picture to zoom on my phone, so I can't really see the white fuzz too well...

Comment: They are some kind of mealybug.

Comment: @Karl Kjer I think you are correct! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug#/media/File:Mealybugs_feeding_on_hibiscus_plant.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in @KarlKjer 's comment, this insect is a *Pseudococcidae*, or commonly known as **Mealybugs**. The exact species is difficult to find due to picture quality.

> **Mealybugs** are insects in the family *Pseudococcidae*, unarmored scale insects found in moist, warm climates. Many species are considered pests as they feed on plant juices of greenhouse plants, house plants and subtropical trees and also act as a vector for several plant diseases.
>
> Mealybugs occur in all parts of the world. Most occur naturally only in warmer parts, and get introduced into greenhouses and other buildings in cooler countries. It is unlikely that any live in the Arctic or Antarctic, except perhaps in buildings.

Considering that Mealybugs are found basically anywhere on Earth, it's not a surprise to have found them in Israel.

[image]

[image]